# Try to customize output with jq with string concatenation

Tags: string, concatenation, jq

I'd like the output of this command to be on a single line :

```
$ lscpu -J | jq -r '.lscpu[] | select(.field=="CPU(s):").data + " x ", select(.field=="Model name:").data' 
4 x 
AMD A4-6210 APU with AMD Radeon R3 Graphics
```

So I tried this but it outputs ... nothing :

```
$ lscpu -J | jq -r '.lscpu[] | select(.field=="CPU(s):").data + " x " + select(.field=="Model name:").data'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the two items in a list, then join them together :

```
lscpu -J | jq -r '.lscpu |
                  map(select(.field |
                             IN("CPU(s):","Model name:")
                            ).data
                     ) |
                  join(" x ")'
```